# MySQL date difference

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and PHP, and I want to find the difference between two dates.

I have a table named `advertisers`, which has a field `web_start_date`. I want to select all entries where the `web_start_date` is less than 30 days from the current date

Comment: What type is `web_start_date`? `DATETIME`, `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, `int`, etc.

Comment: Michael i am waiting for your answer.......

Comment: I wasn't madly refreshing this page waiting for your comment; you need to use [@their-name](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11098/reply-to-comment-feature-request/35918#35918) if you want to reply to someone

Answer (score 14):

Just use the [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) MySQL function.

Comment: +1 There's no need for adding or subtracting when there's a function designed for the job: `SELECT * FROM advertisers WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), web_start_date) < 30;`

Comment: ...or swap the values round if you are comparing now with future dates: `SELECT * FROM advertisers WHERE DATEDIFF(web_start_date, NOW()) < 30;`

Answer (score 2):

use [DATEDIFF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function of `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE web_start_date < TIMESTAMPADD(DAY, 30, NOW())`

Answer (score -3):

hmmm.. try this, see if it work for you :)

```
SELECT * FROM advertisers WHERE DATE(web_start_date) > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```